# Typescript is validating a JS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

I have a component on a `ts` file that renders a component in `js` file, something like this:

```
// typescript
const MyTSComponent = (props: propsType) => {
  return (
    <MyJSComponent units="m3" /> <-- Error!
  );
}
```

```
// javascript
const MyJSComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{props.units}</div>
  );
}
```

The problem I have is my ts compiler throws an error on the `ts` component on `units` prop that says:

```
Type 'string' cannot be asigned to type 'null | undefined'
```

Why is typescript validating props of a `js` component? Here is my `tsconfig` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "esnext",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "jsx": "react",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules/*"]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can define a interface in TS file say `IMyComponentProps { units: string }` and then create a variable using this interface and pass it like `<MyComponent {...componentProps} />`

Comment: Thank you for asking Rajesh! The problem is that I have a list of 8 props and this error is ocuring after I update TS to version > 4 in a lot of JS components... I clean cache, delete and update node_modules but still happening...